# Regex that accept AlphaNumeric as first & last character and accept having AlphaNumeric with only 0 or 1 hyphen in the middle

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to update the current regex `^[^-]*-?[^-]*$` to take AlphaNumeric only for the first & last character and accept having AlphaNumeric with only 0 or 1 hyphen in the middle in regex C#.

Please check below the valid and invalid values.

**Invalid values:**

```
-A
B2-
A--B
#12
```

**Valid values:**

```
A
A-B
"" // empty
1A
12
```

Please advise?

Thank you,

Comment: Like this? `^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/Wsr9fy/1

Comment: So an empty string should also match like `^(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/hXaRJN/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the whole pattern optional, and only allow starting with chars A-Z 0-9 with an optional part for `-` and again chars A-Z 0-9:

```
 ^(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?)?$
```

If the match should be case insensitive, you can either use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or start the pattern with `(?i)`

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z0-9
  - `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)?` Optionally match `-` and 1+ chars A-Z0-9
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make the whole part optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hXaRJN/1)

Or matching any kind of letter and any kind of number:

```
^(?:^[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:-[\p{L}\p{N}]+)?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFff6c/1)